# How do I pull a branch created by another collaborator in a shared repository?

Tags: git, github

I think this is easy to do, but the error is somewhere else in my structure... I've been searching but am stuck.  I have tried 
`git pull collaboratorsbranch https://github.com/username/project.git` 
but I get 
`fatal: Invalid refspec https://github.com/username/project.git`

I think there's something wrong with my origin/master but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Git pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) takes the following arguments:

```
git pull [<remote name>] [<refspec>]
```

or, to be more specific to your current problem:

```
git pull [<remote name>] [<branch to pull from>]
```

You're doing something like the following:

```
git pull [branch to pull from] [address of remote]
```

which won't work.

If you haven't already, you'll need a [remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) set up to point at the shared repository, which I'm assuming is https://github.com/username/project.git. This can be done using:

```
git remote add usernames_repo  https://github.com/username/project.git
```

From there you can pull the branch you want onto a local branch using the pull command:

```
git checkout <branch to pull to>
git pull usernames_repo <branch to pull from>
```

Comment: Your full explanation helped me realize a mistake I was making. I was creating a new remote for each branch! So I deleted all my remotes and setup one remote called 'origin' and did `git pull origin <branch to pull from>' and it worked. Thanks!